# Twitter Bootstrap 3 Checkbox Won't Align with rest of Form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having some trouble with a Twitter Bootstrap form alignment. I have a checkbox that causes the below div's to [incorrectly line up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIKzh.png) with the grid because it's height is only 70px tall when the div next to it is 74px. I could add the CSS to force it to the pixel height needed (see id "test") but I don't want this stay a fixed height when content responds for smaller screens. What would be the best way to fix this?

```
     <div class="container-fluid appointment">  
  <div class="container">    
    <div class="row">
      <h2 class="text-center">Appointment Request</h2>
        <form>
          <div class="col-sm-4">                
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="">Phone Number:</label>
              <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-8">                
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
            </div>
          </div>  

          <div class="col-sm-7">                
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="petname">Pet's Name:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="petname">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-5" id="test">              
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Is your pet neutered or spayed?</label>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label for="neutered"><input type="checkbox" id="neutspay">Neutered/Spayed</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div> 

          <div class="col-sm-4">                
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="pettype">Pet Type:</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="pettype">
                <option>Select Pet Type...</option>
              </select>
            </div> 
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-4">                
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="breed">Breed Type:</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="breed">
                <option>Select Breed...</option>
              </select>
            </div>  
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-2">                
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="age">Pet Age:</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="age">
                <option>Select Pet Age...</option>
                <option value="less than 1">Less than 1 year</option>
                <option value="1">1 Year</option>                                
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">                                                                             
            <div class="form-group">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg">Send Appointment</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add a class "clearfix" for the div containing the checkbox as

```
<div class="col-sm-5" id="test">              
      <div class="form-group clearfix">
          <label>Is your pet neutered or spayed?</label>
          <div class="checkbox">
               <label for="neutered"><input type="checkbox" id="neutspay">Neutered/Spayed</label>
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!